# netfilter: ipset vs iptables recent module

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter, ipset

what exactly are the practical differences between iptables `recent` module and `ipset` ?

I know recent module only allows IPs, whereas `ipset` allows subnets. But other than this, what is the main practical difference? Is it performance? Which one of those should I use?

Comment: One thing for sure is that it greatly depends on the number of rules and the number of simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1):

The `iptables` `recent` module is used for tracking packets that match certain criteria, such as the source IP address and port, and adding them to a list. Once a packet matches the criteria, it can be marked, logged, or dropped. This module is typically used for implementing rate-limiting or firewall rules that limit the number of connections or requests from a particular IP address.

The `ipset` tool, on the other hand, is used for managing large sets of IP addresses or other network objects, such as network ranges, MAC addresses, and ports. These sets can be used by other tools, such as `iptables` or `tc` (traffic control), to apply policies to packets that match the set criteria. `ipset` provides more advanced features than the `recent` module, such as the ability to create sets that are dynamically updated from a network source, such as DNS or a HTTP API.

In terms of performance, `ipset` can be faster than the `recent` module in some scenarios, particularly when dealing with **large sets of IP addresses**. This is because `ipset` uses a **hash table** to store the IP addresses, which allows for efficient lookups and updates.

However, the performance difference between the two tools may not be significant for small sets of IP addresses or for basic rate-limiting or firewall rules. Additionally, the choice of which tool to use ultimately depends on the specific use case and requirements.

If you need to manage a large number of IP addresses or other network objects, or if you need to dynamically update the sets based on external sources, `ipset` may be a better choice. On the other hand, if you only need to track and limit traffic from a specific IP address or port, the `recent` module may be sufficient.

FYI `recent` uses [linked list](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/netfilter/xt_recent.c#L178).

Ref: 
https://linux.die.net/man/8/ipset 
https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Comment: Great explanation!